# Multiplying two numbers in a function?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

I am trying to run a test through jest.
Test code below:

```
  describe('multiply', () => {
        test('multiplies two numbers', () => {
            expect(calculator.multiply([2,4])).toBe(8);
        });
```

My code

```
const multiply = function() {
let toBe = ([`0`] * [`0`]);
return toBe;
};
```

What am I doing wrong here? I am confused by my result.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: where comes `calculator` ?

Comment: const calculator = require('./calculator');
Does that help?

Comment: how is `multiply` a property of that

Comment: what do you think `let toBe = ([`0`] * [`0`]);` does? why isn't your multiply function simply `const multiply = function(a, b) { return a * b }`  or even `const multiply = (a, b) => a * b;`

Answer (score 0):

your multiply function doesn't multiply any parameters.

```
const multiply = (a, b) => a * b;
```

now this function multiplies 2 values.
you can run your test with

```
expect(calculator.multiply(2,4)).toBe(8);
```

I assume your calculator class works fine, so then test would work fine